# How to change date format of timestamps on pivot in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, timestamp, pivot, php-carbon

I'm trying to change the date type of timestamps (created_at, updated_at, deleted_at) globally in the whole application from `timestams` to `timestampsTz`. In migrations it's no problem. In single models either, since I can overwrite the `$dateFormat` parameter of the model.

But I have problem with pivot tables containing timestamps, because they don't inherit any parameters from my models.

Let's say I have a **products** and **attributes** table with **attribute_product** pivot between them containing columns like `value` and `timestamps`. If I try to retrieve all attributes with values and timestamps of a product I would do something like this: `$product->attributes` but I get the error:

```
local.ERROR: Trailing data {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Trailing data at \\vendor\\esbot\\carbon\\src\\Carbon\\Carbon.php:910)
[stacktrace]
#0 \\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Concerns\\HasAttributes.php(716): Carbon\\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2019-06-25 16:1...')
#1 \\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Concerns\\HasAttributes.php(739): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->asDateTime('2019-06-25 16:1...')
#2 \\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Concerns\\HasAttributes.php(532): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->fromDateTime('2019-06-25 16:1...')
#3 \\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model.php(230): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->setAttribute('created_at', '2019-06-25 16:1...')
#4 \\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model.php(248): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->fill(Array)
...
```

The builder retrieves the timestamp in the correct format (e.g. "2019-06-25 16:17:01+02") but when it tryes to hydrate the related models pivot data, it uses the wrong format "Y-m-d H:i:s" and fails.

Is there any proper way to achieve this? Or is there any usable workaround?

Any help appreciated? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried creating an intermediary model for your pivot tables? You should then be able to alter the `dateFormat` property.

For example, you can create a pivot model like so:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class RoleUser extends Pivot
{

}
```

And update the relationship on the other model to use that Pivot model.

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    /**
     * The users that belong to the role.
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->using('App\RoleUser');
    }
}
```

Then because you have a class for the Pivot model you should be able to specify the format.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Even though I didn't create pivot models for all my relations because currently the project has more than 60 tables. Instead I override the `belongsToMany` method on my base model so it uses a common pivot model. So it looks like the problem is solved :)